# Pandas to_sql creates multiple not unique entries

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have created an dataframe in pandas. I use `to_sql` method with SQLalchemy to push the data to an Microsoft SQL database.

```
push_report.to_sql('PERF_TELEMETRY_REPORT_KPI_HD',
                dest_engine,
                schema='PERFORM',
                if_exists='append',
                index=False,
                chunksize=tsql_chunksize,
                method='multi')
```

In the dataframe I have a column with unique `REPORT_ID` (s). The number of rows in dataframe is 250.

After operation finished in the destination table I have 3 duplicates of each initial dataframe row.
So i have 750 rows in destination DB table.

Example:

```
ID      REPORT_ID   OBJECT_ID
105785  19488900    625196
105785  19488900    625196
105785  19488900    625196
105784  19489864    625196
105784  19489864    625196
105784  19489864    625196
```

Comment: probably your database table wasn't empty before, as you use `if_exists='append'` it will create multiple entries if you run your code multiple times

Comment: whats the schema of your table?

Comment: Table was not empty but previous related values was deleted

Comment: Schema was used to arrange user access. In ```PERFORM``` schema we have permission to insert, delete, update data

Comment: I checked to delete all rows before insert the new ones. Same result